# Data Model for Posts and its replies with likes using Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling, feed, getstream-io

I am building NewsFeed app where user can create a post and other people can reply o that post and replies can also have likes.

My Question is how to create a good data model for replies using firebase firestore. I am thinking to create a replies seperate collection with userId and postId combiniation. and also i have to post that feed into the getStream.io

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. So what's wrong with your idea?

Comment: @AlexMamo there is nothing wrong with y idea, i just want to know that are submcollections are good or should i create seperate collection for replies and link it with post? i will not query to fetch those data because i will generate feed from getStream.io. you can say i am using firebase just for backup

Comment: If your idea satisfies your queries, why not?

Comment: yes my idea satisfies all my requirements for now. thanks